# how to remove duplicate column from rollup row

Tags: php, mysql, rollup, subtotal

I want to use rollup with group by for sub totals for my MySQL table. But the problem is that it repeat other columns in roll row (sub total row) which I don't want. I only want subtotal.

I achieved this by using union but union slow the MySQL query as i have to use two union ( one for sub total and one for grand total)

my output

| name | last name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| umar | nazir | 30 |
| ali | ahmed | 20 |
| sub tot | nazir | 50 |

Comment: Show query text.